Flutter app showing Android icon instead of custom icon after adding yookassa_payments_flutter package
I'm building a Flutter app and I've added the yookassa_payments_flutter package (version 1.5.0) to my pubspec.yaml file. However, after adding the package, my app is showing the Android icon instead of my custom icon. I've tried removing the package and the issue goes away, but I need to use the package for payment processing.
Error Messages: None
Flutter and Package Versions:

Flutter: 3.24.3
yookassa_payments_flutter: 1.5.0
Dart: 3.5.3
DevTools: 2.37.3

I've tried removing the package and the issue goes away. I've also tried searching online for solutions, but I haven't found anything that works.

Same problem.. Any solution?

Try this:

Check android/app/src/main/res/ for conflicting icons.
Run flutter clean, flutter pub get, and flutter run.
Ensure custom icons are referenced correctly in
AndroidManifest.xml.
Use flutter_launcher_icons package to regenerate icons.
Try a different yookassa_payments_flutter version or check for
updates.
Restart the emulator (if any is being used)


Doesn't work for me
